# What documents should I submit with the antrag form (Permanent Residence (Bluecard))

Tags: germany, blue-card

The lady from ausländerbehörde asked for the following docs, and also attached application form

- Rentenversicherungsverlauf Gehaltsabrechnungen der letzten 3 Monate
- Arbeitsvertrag & Bescheinigung über das weitere Bestehen des
- Arbeitsverhältnisses Mietvertrag & Nebenkostenabrechnung
- Sprachzertifikat B1 /A1 (bei Blaue Karte 33 M), ggf. Nachweis
- abgeschlossene inländische Ausbildung / Studium Zertifikat
- „Einbürgerungstest“ (oder „Leben in Deutschland“), ggf. Nachweis
  abgeschlossene inländische Ausbildung / Studium

I have all the required docs mentioned in the email but on the antrag form there are some additional documents (listed below), do I need to attach those as well

- Führungszeugnis
- Aufforderung zur ärztlichen Untersuchung

Comment: Edited your question to make it easier to understand what you're asking, feel free to revert if you feel I misrepresented your intentions.

Comment: This doesn't look like a list for an application for permanent residence to me. The last point is not a document at all but a 'request for a medical examination'. Please supply an image of the application form.

Comment: This may be a general form listing things conditionaly based on what you are appling for.  Führungszeugnis would be a **criminal record** that would cover the time spent in Germany and can often be applied for online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you generally do not have to attach those. If you just want to double check, you can check what documents they usually ask on the website of your Behörde.

Since you have all the document you were asked for, I would not loose any further time submitting those since it can take some time for them to process and you want to be in the line as quickly as possible.